# Get JSON keys for any file

Tags: jquery, json, key

I get a CSV file with php and I encode it in JSON, and I make an ajax request with jQuery to get this JSON. In JSON, keys are column's names. I want to display it as a table.

But each CSV upload can have differents column names, so JSON differents keys. This is my code: (I try only for the first three columns)

```
$.ajax({
    url: "CSV.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: {},
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (jsonStr) {
        var trHTML = '';
        $.each(jsonStr, function (i, item) {
            trhtml += '<tr><td>' + item.NOM + '</td><td>' + item.PRENOM + '</td><td>' + item.ADRESSE + '</td></tr>';
        });

        $('#result').append(trhtml);
    }
});
```

When I try to put column name in an array, and pass it dynamically, the return value is: undefined

```
$.ajax({
    url: "CSV.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: {},
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (jsonStr) {
        var trHTML = '';
        var colname = jsonStr[0];
        var test = Object.keys(colname);
        var col1 = test[1];     // NOM
        var col2 = test[2];     // PRENOM
        var col3 = test[3];     // ADRESSE

        $.each(jsonStr, function (i, item) {
            trhtml += '<tr><td>' + item.col1 + '</td><td>' + item.col2 + '</td><td>' + item.col3 + '</td></tr>';
        });

        $('#result').append(trhtml);
    }
});
```

So, How can I get dynamically json keys?

Comment: Can you post your sample `JSON` ?

Comment: can't use dot notation for variable property names ...  use `[]` notation like `item[col1]`

Comment: [
    {
        "NOM": "Dupont",
        "PRENOM": "Jean",
        "ADRESSE": "rue des pres",
        "CP": "75000",
        "VILLE": "Paris"
    },
    {
        "NOM": "Marie",
        "PRENOM": "Julien",
        "ADRESSE": "rue des acacia",
        "CP": "75000",
        "VILLE": "Paris"
    },
    {
        "NOM": "Morvan",
        "PRENOM": "Luc",
        "ADRESSE": "rue des bois",
        "CP": "75000",
        "VILLE": "Paris"
    }
    
]

Comment: It works with item[col1], thanks !!